# python script has an output, but in a shell for loop it doesn't output

Tags: python, shell, for-loop, directory, output

I have a python script that takes two arguments, and when I run it the script outputs 3 new files as it is supposed too:

```
>>> python importpymol2.py 65_*.pdb BTB_old.pdb
```

but when I put is through a shell loop that also changes directories(the script is in each directory):

```
>>>> for i in *;do current_dir=$PWD; cd $PWD/*;python importpymol2.py 65_*.pdb BTB_old.pdb;cd $current_dir; done
```

but, it runs perfectly normal with the exception that it doesn't output the files.... how can I get it to output the files?

Comment: How is `cd $PWD/*` supposed to work if there are multiple matches for `*` (or you wouldn't have a loop at all). Is that snippet actually working correctly at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a typo in your shell command, try to change it to:

```
for i in *;do current_dir=$PWD; cd $PWD/$i;python ../importpymol2.py 65_*.pdb BTB_old.pdb;cd $current_dir; done
```

(I assume importpymol2.py is located in your $PWD.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to cd back.  Instead, just run in a subshell:

```
for i in *; do ( cd $i; python ...; ); done
```